# Python: Remove an item from list

Tags: python, list

My data looks like this:

```
hashtags = [['mobile', 'data', 'cx', 'rt'],
            ['drivers', 'data', 'analytics'],
            ['data'],
            ['data', 'math']]
```

I want to remove 'data' from the list above so the expected output would be:

```
hashtags = [['mobile', 'cx', 'rt'],
            ['drivers', 'analytics'],
            ['math']]
```

I tried:

```
for item in hashtags:
    print item.remove('data')
```

But, the code return:

```
None
None
None
None
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: One issue not yet addressed below is that you should generally not be trying to use the result of list.append() and list.remove() expressions.  The list is changed in place, but the return value is None unless the operation fails.  Presumably, what you want is just the modified list, so you have to remove first, then print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `list comprehension`.

```
>>> hashtags = [['mobile', 'data', 'cx', 'rt'],
            ['drivers', 'data', 'analytics'],
            ['data'],
            ['data', 'math']]
>>> [[j for j in i if j != 'data'] for i in hashtags]
[['mobile', 'cx', 'rt'], ['drivers', 'analytics'], [], ['math']]
>>> [k for k in [[j for j in i if j != 'data'] for i in hashtags] if len(k) > 0 ]
[['mobile', 'cx', 'rt'], ['drivers', 'analytics'], ['math']]
```

For better readability,

```
>>> [lst for lst in [[itm for itm in sublst if itm != 'data'] for sublst in hashtags] if len(lst) > 0 ]
[['mobile', 'cx', 'rt'], ['drivers', 'analytics'], ['math']]
>>>
```

Comment: A list comprehension is overkill, and it's much harder to read and maintain.

Comment: You got my upvote though I think it would be easier to read if you would use proper variable names, i.e. `[[itm for itm in sublist if itm != 'data'] for sublist in hashtags]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get you desired result like this:

```
for list in hashtags:
    list.remove('data')
    if list == []:
        hashtags.remove(list)
```

Comment: Why not just `if not list`?

Comment: I think both are providing same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The function `item.remove( ... )` doesn't return a value, it simply removes said value from the list. You should just do this:

```
hashtags.remove(["data"])
```

And then print the list like this:

```
print hashtags
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this has a downvote. The answer is much more clear and concise than the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
for sublist in hashtags:
    sublist.remove('data')
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP had in mind. The OP wants to remove the item `["data"]` from the list entirely, not remove `"data"` from `["data"]`.